# Qt5/Yocto: capture screen/screen recording of deployed aplication

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, yocto, screen-recording

There's the need to capture the GUI (if possible with sound) for some videos. Using the desktop-build instead of the deployed app would be possible, but for a more native approach I would run this on the device.
Setup consists of an ARM board (quadcore, so there should be enough performance left) with Yocto Linux and a Qt 5.12-based build.

I've done some extensive web-search, but found nothing but some hints of how to capture single screens. Does Qt offer something inbuilt?

Any hints (key words) welcome!

edit 20210311: Thanks for the input so far. But - since no developers are shall do the recording - no tampering with the code of the app is wanted.
Yes, it is an QML-based app.
Current state: there are strong hints that crosscompiling ffmpeg and grabbing the frames from /dev/fb0 will be the best. But I haven't given it a shot yet.

Comment: There's nothing built-in to Qt that does that for you unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using QML, you can grab images of any element using the [`Item.grabToImage()` method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method). Otherwise, you'll want to use a display server method, which means you'll need to learn X11 or Wayland functions, depending on which your Yocto setup uses.

Comment: Thank you for that advice. Since we have several hundreds 'Items', this would lead to lots of effort. Also: neither Wayland norX11, but eglfs.

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use [QtAvi](https://iondev.ro/qtavi/) library and create a self arrange video from the widget's screen-shot. for snap-shot, you can use [this method](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#grabToImage-method) for QML and bellow code for the widget s

```
QImage img(mywidget.size());
QPainter painter(&img);
mywidget.render(&painter);
img.save("/some/file.jpg");
```

record the audio with [QMediaRecorder](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediarecorder.html) and send it to the QtAvi as an audio file.in [this link](https://iondev.ro/qtavi/download.html), you can find a complete example of QtAvi Library.